# Is there a way to make DotNetNuke's HTML editor produce relative links instead of absolute links?

Tags: html, dotnetnuke

I've tried adding the `LinksUseRelativeUrls` attribute to the proper element in web.config, but it didn't stop DotNetNuke's HTML editor from inserting absolute links whenever you link to another page, rather than inserting relative links.

I'm using DNN 6, and the default RadEditorProvider.  Has anyone been able to fix this without having to manually edit links every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the "Enable Relative URL Links" defined in the HTML Editor Manager page? That setting should work you're using the DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider. I just tested on my site and the links are all being built relatively in the HTML module.

Comment: Evidently you have to click on one of the configuration names in order to see the options, which don't appear clickable.  At any rate, thanks for the answer, you're a lifesaver!